# MySQL Limit by OR

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there's a way in MySQL to, say, LIMIT 1 for each OR. As in, if I have a MySQL statement `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Johnny' OR username = 'Matthew' OR username = 'Andy' OR username = 'Sandra' ORDER BY date DESC` but I want to return only one result from each username (or, in this case, the latest post from each person). I've tried `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (username = 'Johnny' LIMIT 1) OR (username = 'Matthew' LIMIT 1) OR (username = 'Andy' LIMIT 1) OR (username = 'Sandra' LIMIT 1) ORDER BY date DESC` but that's about all I could think of (and it didn't work).
Thanks in advance,
Matthew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to combine separate queries:

```
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Johnny'  LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Matthew' LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Andy'    LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Sandra'  LIMIT 1)
```

Alternatively, you can group the results by username:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     posts
WHERE    username IN ('Johnny','Matthew','Andy','Sandra')
GROUP BY username
```

Both of these queries as given above will return indeterminate rows for each user (which may or may not be what you need).  To fetch specific rows, please specify how MySQL can determine which rows you want.

---

**UPDATE**

To obtain the most recent posts for each user and order the resultset from newest to oldest:

```
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Johnny'  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Matthew' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Andy'    ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Sandra'  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

And:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     posts NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   username, MAX(date) AS date
           FROM     posts
           WHERE    username IN ('Johnny','Matthew','Andy','Sandra')
           GROUP BY username
         ) AS t
GROUP BY username -- only required if multiple posts might have the same date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: what's the difference between the UNION ALL used here and the just UNION used below? Also, how would I do the equivalent of `ORDER BY date DESC`? thanks :D

Comment: @IMAPC: "The default behavior for `UNION` is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional `DISTINCT` keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal. With the optional `ALL` keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the `SELECT` statements."  Therefore adding `ALL` is more efficient if you don't need MySQL to scan and remove duplicates (as is the case here, since duplicates are impossible).

Comment: @IMAPC: When you say that you wish to `ORDER BY date DESC`, do you mean that you want the most recent post from each user returned in any order or that you want a post from each user returned in descending date order?  Or both: that you want the most recent posts from each user returned in descending date order?

Comment: wait, for the GROUP BY one, how would I order it by both (most recent posts from each user returned in descending date order, as you said)?

Comment: @IMAPC: It's not entirely straightforward--you have to use a subquery to obtain the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).  See my revised answer.

Comment: o.o umm, sorry, but I'm not the best at this kind of thing :\ could you point me towards an explanation with a better example, or explain how I might apply the subquery to the group by? thanks :D

Comment: the group by approach will drop other column info

Comment: @eggyal I mean if you need info such as "age" you cannot use the **group by** approach ,as it is lost when you group by. so I prefer the union_all approach

Comment: @zinking: However, if one joins the group result with the table (as I do in the fourth example shown), one is able to retrieve all of the data.  This is how one usually obtains groupwise maxima/minima/etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about using union?

Edited with thanks to @eggyal correction:

```
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Johnny' LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Matthew' LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = 'Andy' LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html): "To apply `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` to an individual `SELECT`, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the `SELECT`."

Comment: but what if I wanted to order all of the results (as in, the results from all the different SELECTs)? should I just put `ORDER BY date DESC` after the final )?

Comment: sorry, it's in the manual which you linked, maybe I should read it next time before I ask (:

Comment: Yes. Just add ORDER BY date DESC.